# Why cant i put PATH in vim~/.zshrc why is anaconda showing up in there?

Tags: flutter, zshrc

I cant add PATH for flutterfire (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwQZV.png)

i ran vim ~/.zshrc to add the path but i cant add or edit the terminal page.

Is there any other way to add the path? I have already deactivated conda but somehow it still pops up there

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead of this use plain text